# How to secure Dash-Apps within Flask-App with Flask-Login?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-login, plotly-dash

Im trying to wrap my head around this problem for 2 days now and i cant find any right solution on the web and forums for this problem.

I cant secure a dash-app within flask-app with @login_required decorator. I can call the dash-app with in the blueprint route with @login_required to secure it and  redirect it to the dash-app.

But if i call the dash-app directly like_ localhost:5000/dashapp1 then it goes directly to the app without login.

Is there any solution out there that secure the Dash-App within the Flask-App with the same Flask-Login initiation?

thanks

Comment: You can check my solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011735/2180721

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60853537/320399 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/57629586/320399

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://github.com/okomarov/dash_on_flask) is what you are looking for this guy also uses blueprints in someway. I was looking for how to structure flask application with blueprints and dash and found this. It is little bit complex but worth to try.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Ive been keeping my projects on the side because i cant find a solution for this.

Comment: Please mark it answered. If this answer satisfies you.

Comment: I will first look at it, if its really the solution. Thanks and ill get back to you...

Comment: Okay. I hope it helps.